# how to write a Indian name 'Agrawal' in Japanese language?

Tags: names

how to write a Indian name 'Agrawal' in Japanese language? Any help will be appreciated.

Is it same as "アグラワル "?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess アグラワル would be fine. It might be アグラウァル because I’ve seen katakana use ウァ sometimes too. These the best I can make of It. I don’t know the exact pronunciation of the name in Indian though. Under normal circumstances, Japanese people tend to listen to the name and make the kana up that moment. But based on what I imagine the name to sound like, this is my best guess.